# Plot Single Column Data File Histogram in RStudio

Tags: r, csv, histogram, bins

How can I display a histogram with 20 bins for the attached file? The two lines of code I attempted to use are shown below.

d=read.table("wgci_mAdc2.csv")
hist(d)

I get an error message which says, "Error in hist.default(d) : 'x' must be numeric"

My data file looks something like the list below.
86.60
91.40
85.30
86.90
89.60
58.40
59.00
58.80
58.60
89.20
91.90
90.60
88.10
89.20
84.40
88.90
85.00
58.30
57.60
58.10
89.80
58.00
91.50
58.10
57.40
58.00
90.10
58.10
58.90
57.70
91.80
58.70
91.80
58.40
57.40
58.00
87.60
95.20
91.20
88.00
82.90
92.60
89.00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is not recognised as numeric.
Have you tried as.numeric() ?

```
d=read.table("wgci_mAdc2.csv")
d =as.numeric(unlist(d))
hist(d)
```

Comment: I tried to use your code and got the following error message.   > d =as.numeric(d)
Error: 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

Comment: Ive edited my answer, could you try to unlist()

Comment: Yes, the change worked. Thank you for your valuable assistance.